# How to display none dynamic genrated class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

need to hide dynamic class in a table row.
I want to know how I can hide the dynamic class which is showing on the table row.
Into other words need to hide a row from the table which contains this dynamic class. If I add rule to make `display:none;` when I put CSS into files it's still showing there also I have to use the jquery something like below

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dos").hide();
  });
  </script>
```

but it's still showing row there .
please check screenshot 
http://prntscr.com/eyl1h9
here is webiste https://silverforte.com
first add to cart then checkout , sign in as a customer then fill up the billing details click to continue then select shipping step will show order confirm and you will be find all there .
I hope there will be a solutions for that

Comment: '_need to hide dynamic class_' How is the dynamic class generated ?

Comment: @Dan Philip, it's showing when you order something otherwise there showing nothing it's generating with the help of biocommerce js and the js file i cannot access.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS

```
.dos{
  display:none;
}
```

or write your javascript code at the bottom without the document.ready

Comment: the class is generating dynamically, mean to say there is not the class in HTML it's coming with the help of js or javascript.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2fjuykr8/ - "the class is generating dynamically" - that is **completely** irrelevant to css styles

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj The reason why `$(".dos").hide();` doesn't work is probably, because you fire jQuery hide before the class `.dos` gets "generated" - using the css style is the easiest way to go.

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj. your question is irrelevant . unable to understand your problem

Comment: ok so simply that in my big commerce website in order confirmations sections need to hide a row from the table .

Comment: @Adem key i have used you jsfiddle its still showing there.

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj try then `tr.SubTotal.dos{display:none!important;}` - you probably have problem with another style overriding display none, so you will have to crank up importance of the override style

Comment: @Adam K  please check both screenshots http://prntscr.com/eylm4f   it is still showing http://prntscr.com/eylmcg

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj unfortunately ScreenShot won't tell me much... Do you have a link to live running website? It definitely has to be some triviality, that is preventing it from working.

Comment: @Adam K I have already added website link into the question  BTW here it is  https://silverforte.com

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj Have you tried looking if you are adding anything at all? I have clicked through the eshop to the cart page and no wonder it's not working, when the actual code, you are trying to add there is not showing anywhere in the HTML. How could the style work, when it's not there at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142148/discussion-between-raj-kumar-bhardwaj-and-adam-k).

Comment: @Adam k you need to check out as a guest then it will ask you for fill up your details, after that, you click to continue button, same up to the step order confirm and you will find the row there with inspect element you can see the class there.

Answer (score 0):

you can check priority of css selector using devTools of chrome,when `$('.dos').hide()` have no effect.

Comment: it does not work because there is not class into HTML it's coming online which we cannot able to access. This is the main problem